# Jquery div in div breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                        jQuery(".content").hide();
                        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
                        jQuery(".link").click(function()
                        {
                            jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
                        });;
                    });
 </script>


<a href="#" class="link">dfsd</a>


    <div class="content"> 
            dfsgdgsfsdfggdfs
        </div>
```

Is working fine however when I put  in another div:

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="content"> 
       dfsgdgsfsdfggdfs
   </div>
</div>
```

How to fix this?
I have tried .test.link etc but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(this).next(".test").find('.content').slideToggle(500);
```

OR

```
jQuery(this).next(".test").slideToggle(500);
```

Answer (score 1):

replace this line: `jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);`

with this one: `jQuery("div.content").slideToggle(500);`

Comment: this will open all the .content in the document at the same time.

Comment: correct, but assuming his code, there is only one. 
but thanks for the comment, I do like people who care to give feedback :) 
+1 for this point.

Comment: yes, you should take care of feedback, since this is a community. ;)

Answer (score 1):

$(this).next(".content") looks for siblings

> Description: Get the immediately
>   following sibling of each element in
>   the set of matched elements. If a
>   selector is provided, it retrieves the
>   next sibling only if it matches that
>   selector.

use $(this).next(".test")